# matrix = *((fxMatrix*)&d3dMatrix); //Evil?

Tags: c++, matrix, directx, vtable

I've been using

```
matrix = *((fxMatrix*)&d3dMatrix);
```

for quite a while. It worked fine until my screen turned black and received a bucket of frustration on my desk.

fxMatrix contains 4 fxVectors. fxVector used to be 16 bytes, but now it was suddenly 20. This was because it inherited fxStreamable, which added the vTable.

So one solution is of course just to not inherit fxStreamable, and leave a comment saying that it must always be 16 bytes and never more.

Another solution would be to make conversion functions, and copy the matrix completely. This makes it more secure, but has an impact on the performance. I suppose this is the best idea.

Another solution is to not convert at all, and stick to D3DXMATRIX, but this makes the engine inconsistent and I personally really dislike this idea.

What is your opinion?

Comment: You should do what's cleanest, not what's fastest; the two aren't mutually exclusive anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do this, add an assert or compile-time test:

```
assert(sizeof(fxMatrix) == sizeof(D3DMatrix));

BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(fxMatrix) == sizeof(D3DMatrix));
```

For bonus points, it's also possible to check that each value is in the same place.

But yeah, it's kind-of evil (like nuclear power), so you should either handle it with proper precautions or don't do it at all. ;)

Comment: This could even be expanded, and instead of an error call a proper conversion function, and in the other case `#else` just leave the original code.

Comment: You can't test sizeof with the preprocessor, you'll have to use a variant of static assert.

Comment: @Mephane: I was mistaken that it could be done with the preprocessor, but since the expression is constant you can use regular if-else and you'd get the correct code called without overhead anyway. :)

Answer (score 4):

the impact of conversion functions might very well be negligible. Use that solution, unless a profiler can prove it's a bottleneck. Such casts are indeed rather evil, else you wouldn't have to ask this quetsion.

Answer (score 3):

You could just make an explict assignment operator:

```
// Code Was this:
matrix = *((fxMatrix*)&d3dMatrix);

// Add the assignment operator
class fxMatrix
{
    // STUFF
    fxMatrix& operator=(D3DXMATRIX const& rhs)
    {
         // Explicitly copy.
             // Do in here what you were letting the compiler do before.
         return *this;
    }
    // STUFF
};
// New Code
matrix = d3dMatrix;
```

Comment: Why an assignment operator instead of a constructor?

Comment: @GMan: Probably should have both. It just looked like an assignment for this situation. Its hard to tell with such a little snipit.

Comment: You only need a constructor, because assignment will already work.

Answer (score 0):

Inherit from both, and use C++ casts. The C++ compiler will then see your true intent, and make the 4 byte adjustment. It's quite unlikely you'll see the effect of a 4 byte pointer adjustment.